# ADDing file via Browsable Api in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, rest

I am new to django and rest framework. There are two models named Video and Course and ManyToMany relationship as described below.

```
class Video(models.Model):
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='static', null=True, blank=True)


class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    video = models.ManyToManyField(Video)
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

When I add new course via admin panel, I can add new video to server by + sign in the right side. However, when I try to add new course via browsable API,(by POST method) It looks like I can only use videos which are already in the server, so I cant add new one.How can I add new Video when I add new course via api?

Comment: I think the best practice would be to keep your Video objects independent and first upload your Videos and in another step, do a post to create your course providing you Video ids.

This suggestion is because you may use multipart/form-data to upload your Videos and the nested nature is not easily possible using that type of upload requests.